# Can I have List(T).ForEach() that traverses elements strictly in order?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, foreach

There's [`List(T).ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) that performs an action on each element of the list. However MSDN description doesn't say anything about the order in which `List` elements will be traversed and I need to have them traversed strictly in order.

How can I achieve that with `ForEach()`?

Comment: For what it's worth, here's the current implementation of List.ForEach:
https://gist.github.com/1066881

Comment: @Kobi: quote source and license? (at least source, because it'll probably mention the license)

Comment: @sehe - decompiled using IL Spy from .Net's assemblies, I didn't check the license, but it should fall under "fair use" for research/learning purposes.

Comment: @Kobi: I think that in the US, decompiling is explicitly illegal in most cases due to the DMCA.  You're better of using the source release, which explicitly allows sharing the source for reference usage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`List<T>.ForEach` *will* go in the same order as a normal `foreach` loop, which is also the natural order of the list.

Yes, the documentation doesn't state it - but it's the obvious behaviour, and I think it's pretty reasonable to rely on that not changing.

(Now `Parallel.ForEach` is a different matter, of course.)

Comment: +1 and the example in the Msdn article posted in the question shows the ordering being conserved. There are some things that don't have to be stated every time

Comment: @Jon: well, to be fair, the [documentation for the foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=VS.100).aspx) instruction itself does not specify the order. Thinking to an extended ForEach where you explicitly pass the ordering would be a nice (if somewhat pointless) exercise. :)

Comment: @paolo: The *real* documentation for `foreach` is the language spec, which gives the order very explicitly. The `List<T>.GetEnumerator` docs talk about the "first" element and "next" element, which aren't as specific as they might be, but that's slightly separate from `foreach` itself.

Comment: @Jon: I could find an explicit statement for ordering only for Arrays. In other cases (since I understand that "foreach" is syntactic sugar for getting an enumerator and calling its MoveNext() repeatedly) I could not find any mention to order. And it makes sense, since you could define an enumerator for structures with no unambiguosly defined "order" (like trees). For Lists the order would be unambiguously defined, though, so it kind of bothers me they haven't given a definition (that I could find) in the spec.

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the elements is essential I would recommend to use a `Queue<T>` (LIFO) or a `Stack<T>` (FIFO) which ensure the order by design. In this case you have to use a classic loop instead using the LINQ extension method or implement it by yourself.

Comment: I don't think I agree at all. A List *is* ordered by design - it's how the data stricture supposed to work. It isn't a Set or a Dictionary.

Comment: Alright, it will still depend on the requirements if it shall be possible to insert elements anywhere or just in a certain order, which is not clear in the question. So using a List for a certain order is still perfectly fine, as long as the insertion of new elements is not bound to any other more specific requirements, which might be but was not mentioned yet - however it might be worth to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The `List<T>` class represents an ordered collection of items, so iterating it using enumerators or `ForEach` method **will** preserve the order, even if the documentation is not very clear on this.